# How to prevent hijack of Beaglebone peripheral pins

Tags: debian, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, gpio, u-boot

I have customized my beaglebone's device tree. Some on-chip peripherals such as I2C,UART, etc. and corresponding pins on P8 and P9 headers are enabled and some others are disabled.

In order to prevent users from hijacking pins occupied by the peripherals, I need to prevent user from export, unexport, change of direction and value of pins used by peripherals. In other words if user tries to execute

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

should result in an error (When uboot overlays are enabled in /boot/uENV.txt by setting

```
enable_uboot_overlays=1
```

in mentioned file and commenting

```
disable_uboot_overlay_video = 1
```

exporting of LCD pins results in such an error)

The .dts file written by me however enables I2C1 peripheral, but permits user to change direction and value on SDA and SCL pins.

I added nodes to am335x-boneblack.dts file as specified below:
the node

```
pinmux_i2c1_pins {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <0x158 0x32 0x15c 0x32>;
    linux,phandle = <0xdd>;
    phandle = <0xdd>;
};
```

was added to "pinmux@800" node ,

```
i2c@4802a000 {
    compatible = "ti,omap4-i2c";
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x0>;
    ti,hwmods = "i2c2";
    reg = <0x4802a000 0x1000>;
    interrupts = <0x47>;
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";          
    pinctrl-0 = <0xdd>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    linux,phandle = <0xa0>;
    phandle = <0xa0>;           
    };
```

was added to "ocp" node, and finally

```
i2c1_pins ="/ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c1_pins";
```

was added to "__symbols__" node.

Should I change uboot or in .dts file some code should be added?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you need to add keyword `strict` to your pin control device node in DT. In this case whoever first comes first served.

Comment: *"In order to prevent users from hijacking pins..."* -- You're conflating pins with GPIO, and both are managed resources, just like memory.  If you have properly assigned pins to a peripheral using **pinctrl**, then those pins cannot be used as GPIO.  Only unassigned pins would be available for use as GPIO.  Only free GPIOs can be `export`ed through **sysfs**.  *"The .dts file written by me ... permits user to change... "* -- Then you haven't properly assigned the pins.   Maybe you should enable **pinctrl** subsystem debug capability, or show more of your **dts** changes.

Comment: Thanks for replies. My .dts source is uploaded here:
https://github.com/mmisagh/device-tree/blob/master/am335x-boneblack.dts

Comment: Your monolithic  **.dts** is impossible to read, since it uses hex values instead of the convenient macros.  The preferred convention is to `#include` the standard **.dtsi** for the SoC (e.g. `#include "am33xx.dtsi"`), and then add nodes to amend those base definitions.  Since you have a development board rather than a custom board (?), you would also include **am335x-bone-common.dtsi** and **am335x-boneblack-common.dtsi**.  Then restrict your customizations to the **.dts**, which makes the changes highly visible.

Comment: As previously mentioned, maybe you should enable **pinctrl** subsystem debug capability via `make menuconfig` .

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to do the task!
In a kernel module I wrote:

```
...
#include <linux/gpio.h>

gpio_request(4);     // for requesting GPIO0_4
...
```

loading this LKM prevents from these pin(s) being exported by user.